# Is it possible to use HDFS storage types/policies together with HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase

HDFS has a feature called [storage types/policies](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ArchivalStorage.html) - it makes possible to store files on stores with different properties (fast SSD or slow but cheap archival storage).

I wonder if it's possible to use this feature through HBase?

My use case is that I have some data that is "hot" and is expected to be accessed frequently so I want to put it in "hot" (SSD) storage and some data is "cold" and is accessed infrequently so I want to put it on a cheaper storage. And I'm trying to find out how to organize this with HBase/HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that Storage policy let you specify a policy [on a file or directory](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ArchivalStorage.html#Storage_Policy_Resolution) and they are applied according to certain rules.

We should remember that during HBase instalation we specify the HDFS directory where data is stored, for example:

```
<property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:8030/hbase</value>
</property>
```

So, `/hbase` is a HDFS directory where you can specify policies. We know that the HBSE directory structure would be something like:

```
hdfs://hbase/data/MyFirstNamespace/MyTable1
hdfs://hbase/data/MyFirstNamespace/MyTable2
```

Therefore, I would set up a Storage policy at directory level in HDFS, for example, `Cold` for MyTable1 and `All_SSD` for MyTable2:

```
hdfs storagepolicies -setStoragePolicy -path /hbase/data/MyFirstNamespace/MyTable1 -policy Cold
hdfs storagepolicies -setStoragePolicy -path /hbase/data/MyFirstNamespace/MyTable2 -policy All_SSD
```

This needs to be done after you create a new HBase table.

Answer (score 0):

The HBase data is stored in HDFS (If HDFS is the target storage) under a path configured with property `hbase.rootdir`. You can find the value of it from `hbase-site.xml`. You can then apply the HDFS storage policy against that HDFS path.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow use different policies for different tables?

Comment: As far I know, there is no way you can apply this policies from any HBase interface. IIRC, you can find the specific directories for each table under `${hbase.rootdir}/data` or `${hbase.rootdir}/data/default` with the name of tables. You can individually pick those table hfile storage directories and apply respective storage policy, instead of applying on the parent folder of `hbase.rootdir`. I am not sure this might be a best approach as it involves management overhead whenever we create new tables etc.